# Git-Annex hangs

Tags: git, git-annex

I am experimenting with git-annex and I think I must be doing something wrong. I have git-annex installed on the machine. I then did the following

```
$ mkdir annex  
$ cd annex/  
$ git init  
Initialized empty Git repository in /annex/.git/  
$ git annex init "test data"  
init test data ok  
(Recording state in git...)  
$ git annex add --backend=SHA1 .  
$ git commit -am "initial repo"   
On branch master  
Initial commit  
nothing to commit  
$ touch test.txt # test.txt has a line "this is a test"  
$ git annex add .  
add test.txt
```

At this moment, my command line hangs - the git annex add . seems to not be able to complete. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you please install `strace`, then run `strace git anned add .` (the last command before the failure) and update your post with the last ~40 lines of the `strace` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up being a problem was [PPA](https://github.com/datalad/datalad/issues/12)

Comment: Could you detail how you solved this and what you mean by PPA? I believe I am experiencing the same issue, and your answer (or the GitHub thread linked to) do not help at all.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them It's been some time and I don't remember the details.